# Multiple WAMP Servers on the Same PC

Tags: wampserver

I had installed WAMP server on my C: drive and had several databases created in the embedded mysql instance of it. Later I installed another WAMP server instance on my D: drive. Now I can run the wamp server instance in my D: drive and I can run the other WAMP server instance on my C: drive also (1 instance at a time) but the problem is even though I run the WAMP instance in my C: drive it dosen't show my old Databases and old Aliases dosen't work!

Now I want to switch back to my old WAMP server instance in C: drive. How could I fix it?

Comment: why install two wamp servers? you can have two apps and two databases in one?

Comment: I wanted to save space on my C: drive. that's the reason for installing 2 wamp server instances.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not tested it but you need to change ports of apache and mysql server.

Check out http://www.websysdynamics.com/Web-Tech-Blog/how-to-run-xampp-and-wamp-on-same-machine-in-windows-environment.html

It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. I succesfully installed a new version and moved over some sites, only to discover later the old version doesn't work properly anymore. I think some global path variables may be overwritten or something. The old wamp now makes `localhost` point to the new wamp's www folder and indeed `localhost/phpmyadmin` only shows the new wamps databases. So future readers be warned!

more info about why you shouldnt try to do this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/994013/run-two-wamp-servers-installed-in-different-drives-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

You would try to update the configuration located at **wampmanager.conf** for different versions of WAMP. There you can set the MySQL version,, application etc.

The post [Install both 32 bit and 64 bit WAMP server](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1489816759-Install-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-WAMP-server) would give your some hints.